# I get an error when I do 'yarn start'(Required package: @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object)

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json

I get an error when I do `yarn start`. I search that in the other relevant questions of the stack, but I did not find the solution to my problem. I thinks dependencies of my package.json is correct.

This is my error:

[image]

**Edit:**

I get this error after of run:

```
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --dev && yarn
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As stated by the error message, it appears yarn was expecting [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object) as a dependency. So the problem may be solved by installing it with:

`yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --dev && yarn`

Comment: This is means I should run this code in cmd?: `yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --dev && yarn`

Comment: Yes, it's a command to install that particular plugin as a dependency for your project. So open the command line while in your project folder and run this command.

Comment: Yes, it works, very thanks. but still, I get an error, but I can close that and see my output!!!! I edit now my question for that you see.

Comment: `&& yarn` is necessary at the end of code?